# uid is not working in action defined in xml

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

In ODOO application I want to use domain in action to filter records assigned to currently logged user, but 'uid' is not working

```
<act_window 
id          = "spanio_complaint_to_me_action" 
name        =   "My Works"
res_model   =   "spanio.complaint.register"
domain      =   "[('assigned_to','=', uid)]"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is working while using normal action definition instead of short hand definition

```xml
<record id="spanio_complaint_to_me_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">My Works</field>
    <field name="res_model">spanio.complaint.register</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="spanio_complaint_register_tree" />
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="domain">[('assigned_to','=',uid)]</field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this context use user.id not uid

Comment: i already tried with user.id but it shows an error 'user' is not defined